# Automatically sort all Arrays in controller when getting from database PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, sorting, oop

So I have this controller that passes an associative array called $pagedata to the view. Inside this array are 3 more associative arrays, and the view renders 3 select elements with the array data as options. I want to sort the 3 arrays but I don't want to write sort 3 times here or add order_by into the query methods, because there are dozens of similar pages and I don't want to write hundreds of sort method calls. I was told I could solve this in the constructor. I was wondering if there's an OOP solution that lets me automatically sort all child arrays inside $pagedata.

```
class Sku extends CI_Controller {
    protected $pagedata = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mc');
    }

    public function inventory()
    {
        $this->pagedata['class_ids'] = $this->mc->get_class_ids();
        $this->pagedata['retail_readys'] = $this->mc->get_all_retail_ready();
        $this->pagedata['statuses'] = $this->mc->get_all_status();
    }
}
```

Edit:
I'm exploring using an ArrayObject or wrapping $pagedata in an object and watch for changes.

Comment: Best option is use Join and get data and pass to controller

Answer (score 0):

ok this will be painfull for codeigniter but yes a kind of solution

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mc');
        $class_ids = $this->mc->get_class_ids();
        $class_ids = $this->sortAscending($class_ids, $key);
        $this->pagedata['class_ids'] = $class_ids;

        $retail_readys = $this->mc->get_all_retail_ready();
        $class_ids = $this->sortAscending($class_ids, $key);
        $this->pagedata['class_ids'] = $class_ids;

        $statuses = $this->mc->get_all_status();
        $statuses = $this->sortAscending($class_ids, $key);
        $this->pagedata['statuses'] = $statuses;
    }

function sortAscending($accounts, $key)
{
    $ascending = function($accountA, $accountB) use ($key) {
        if ($accountA[$key] == $accountB[$key]) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($accountA[$key] < $accountB[$key]) ? -1 : 1;
    };
    usort($accounts, $ascending);

    return $accounts;
}

public function inventory()
{
    // already get values
    //$this->pagedata['class_ids'] = $this->mc->get_class_ids();
    //$this->pagedata['retail_readys'] = $this->mc->get_all_retail_ready();
    //$this->pagedata['statuses'] = $this->mc->get_all_status();
    $this->load->view('index',$this->pagedata);
}

 public function another_function()
{
    // already get values
    //$this->pagedata['class_ids'] = $this->mc->get_class_ids();
    //$this->pagedata['retail_readys'] = $this->mc->get_all_retail_ready();
    //$this->pagedata['statuses'] = $this->mc->get_all_status();

    $this->load->view('another page',$this->pagedata);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this solution mean I have to call $this->sortAscending() for every array that comes back from the database?

Comment: not exactly. by using __construct function you will just call this sortAscending function 3 times not inside all function in class Sku. i will add more codes .@2paws

Comment: I only need to populate these 3 arrays and sort when inventory() is called. If another_function() is called from another route, I'd have to populate other arrays.

Comment: than it will will be certain solution ordering arrays inside functions. maybe you can try adding $this->db->order_by('order_column'); inside __construct() or inside every functions   @2paws